# Multi-Release-War for tomcat8 on jdk10

Tags: java, tomcat, multi-release-jar

I just read about [Multi-Release-Jars](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) what looks like a good advantage. I can not get it working using a Tomcat8 on JDK10 and not getting a stacktrace.

This is my servlet (placed at `webapp.jar!/META-INF/versions/10/de/NanoNanoServlet.class`):

```
package de;
public class NanoNanoServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      System.out.println("10");
  }
}
```

This is my servlet (placed at `webapp.jar!/de/NanoNanoServlet.class`):

```
package de;
public class NanoNanoServlet extends HttpServlet {
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
      System.out.println("Other");
  }
}
```

What I get is the console-output:

```
Other
```

But it must be

```
10
```

Using a Tomcat on JDK10

Comment: *I can not get it working using a Tomcat8 on JDK10 and not getting a stacktrace*...you forgot to mention what's not working or what's failing?

Comment: I assume the issue is that Tomcat is not using the new constructors to open JAR files as MR JARs. One thing you could try is to run with -Djdk.util.jar.enableMultiRelease=force to force it.